# Connection failed to any VPN!

Tags: centos, vpn, networkmanager, pptp

PPTP VPN and OpenVPN don't connect and both return error about VPN Secret in my CentOS 6.4 x64 machine! I've already tested the configurations in Windows and Ubuntu with no problem. I also noticed that my OpenVPN advanced settings lacks the "Proxies" tab in CentOS which is available in Ubuntu! I mention it cause I also should set some settings in Proxies tab as well.

Here are system logs for the issue:

PPTP:

```
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 3180
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' appeared, activating connections
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN connection 'PPTP' (ConnectInteractive) reply received.
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> VPN connection 'PPTP' (Connect) reply received.
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <warn> VPN connection 'PPTP' failed to connect: 'No VPN secrets!'.
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Sep 25 13:07:00 Athlon NetworkManager[1848]: <info> Policy set 'Auto FFR' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

OpenVPN:

```
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn'...
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 10750
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn' appeared, activating connections
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=1846 comm="NetworkManager) interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="NeedSecrets" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn" (uid=0 pid=10750 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service))
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <error> [1411635678.904108] [nm-vpn-connection.c:952] connection_need_secrets_cb(): NeedSecrets failed: dbus-glib-error-quark Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=1846 comm="NetworkManager) interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="NeedSecrets" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn" (uid=0 pid=10750 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service))
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=1846 comm="NetworkManager) interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="Disconnect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn" (uid=0 pid=10750 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service))
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=1846 comm="NetworkManager) interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="Disconnect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn" (uid=0 pid=10750 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service))
Sep 25 12:31:18 Athlon NetworkManager[1846]: <info> Policy set 'Auto FFR' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

I googled the issue and found that there is a related bug in NetworkManager, but I couldn't solve the problem

Comment: Have you attached yourself to the bug, in case no one answers here?

Comment: What do you mean by attaching myself to the bug?

Comment: The bug you found related to VPN and NetworkManager.  Put your email address in the CC field.  In LaunchPad, I believe its the affects me field.  Do this so that when the bug is updated or fixed, you get an email.

Comment: I will report the issue as a bug in CentOS bug tracker if you mean so

Comment: ok, when you do, you ned to point CentOS to the bug you already found